# Name the vegetable from Nilgiri hills

Tags: fruit, indian-cuisine, food-identification

I bought this in [Ooty market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ooty_Municipal_Market) and was told that it is a [Nilgiri hills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilgiri_mountains) specific vegetable. It is pink on the outside and white inside with two hard black seeds in the upper half of it. It tastes sour, very similar to unripe strawberry.

Now, I'd like to know what the name of this vegetable is and whether it can be used in any dishes. Until know, I've been eating it as a snack, just like I would any other bite sized food.

[image: small fruit or vegetable]

Comment: Probably a language barrier when they said it was a vegetable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is a fruit called [Chambakka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chambakka).

There are a few recipes for [chambakka achaar](http://www.cookingandme.com/2010/03/chambakka-achaar-recipe-pickled-water.html), which means pickled chambakka.

But I would try this [chambakka jelly recipe](http://homemaderainbows.blogspot.mx/2010/02/chambakka-jelly.html). It looks delicious!

Comment: Great, that seems to be the one. Cheers!